# c# sending multiple email with different body to multiple recipients from outlook

Tags: c#, email, vsto, office-interop, outlook-addin

I have a task to send multiple emails to multiple recipients with different messages at once from outlook.

for this I have to write an Add-In, which should check the list of recipients given in To from database if is there any message for any one in the list then the message should be appended to the body, this cycle should repeat for each recipient given in To.

I can get the recipient list, check from database, append the message but problem is i could not create multiple message bodies a single mail body is sent to all recipients with all appended messages.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create separate messages (Application.CreateItem or MAPIFolder.Items.Add) if you want to have different recipient lists and/or different message bodies.